# How to count only particular entries in json data

Tags: angularjs, json

I have this sample json data:

```
    {
    "sessionsData" :[{
    "isActive": true,
    "isInactive": false,
    "isScheduled": false,
    "isExpired": false,
    "candidateName":"Payal Singh",
    "email": "ggera@sapient.com"
    },
    {
    "isActive": false,
    "isInactive": true,
    "isScheduled": false,
    "isExpired": false,
    "candidateName":"Shyam Singh",
    "email": "ggera@sapient.com"
    },
    {
    "isActive": false,
    "isInactive": false,
    "isScheduled": true,
    "isExpired": false,
    "candidateName":"Payal Singh",
    "email": "ggera@sapient.com"
    },
    {
    "isActive": false,
    "isInactive": false,
    "isScheduled": false,
    "isExpired": true,
    "candidateName":"Payal Singh",
    "email": "ggera@sapient.com"
    }]
    }
```

Now I want to count only the entries which have "isActive" property set to true by using angular.
Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.sessionsData.filter(function(obj,key){    
                return obj.isActive==true 
})
```

OR:

ECMA6 :

```
var arrFiltered = arr.sessionsData.filter((obj,key)=>  
                obj.isActive==true 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter. Follow this link, it is very detailed.I went around it like this:

```
$scope.activeEntries = $filter('filter')($scope.session.sessionsData, {isActive: true});
```

where $scope.session.sessionsData is the array in which I retrieved the json data.